# Use of "Let" in proofs

Tags: proof-writing, terminology

I'm confused about the use of the word let in proofs. For instance, if we want to prove that $A\subset B$ we can start by saying: 'let $x\in A$'. Are we assuming then that $A$ is non-empty?
Another example: We can prove that if $A\times B\subset C\times D $ then $A \subset C$ and $B \subset D$ starting with let $a\in A$ and $b\in B$ But that is false if $B$ is empty.
What is wrong with that proof?

Comment: You are correct that the empty set should should be considered separately.  Happily, that is not difficult.

Comment: Ok, but is it in this specific case or in general that we should consider the empty set? That is, does "let..." imply the set is non-empty?

Comment: If one writes "Let $x \in A$...", one is implicitly stating that such an $x$ exists, and so $A$ is nonempty.  This is a little sloppy if one has not first verified (or assumed) that $A$ is nonempty, but is generally unlikely to cause confusion or to otherwise be problematic.

Comment: I don't see your question has having anything at all to do with the word "let".  Rather, it is about making sure that you are covering all cases.

Comment: See also https://terrytao.wordpress.com/career-advice/theres-more-to-mathematics-than-rigour-and-proofs/ .

Comment: @XanderHenderson: Actually, that's not true; many people use "let" even when there is no instance (e.g. "let $r∈ℚ$ such that $r^2 = 3$). For more details, see [this post](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/a/18155/1550).

Comment: @lulu: You may want to read the post I just linked, because it **is** a matter of confusing language.

Answer (score 1):

There are two confusing and different uses of “Let.”

In this case, when proving $A\subset B,$ you are saying “Let $x$ run through all elements of $A.$” Then you prove that $x\in B,$ too, proving that:

$$\forall x:x\in A\implies x\in B\tag1$$

In this case, you don’t really need to consider $A$ empty.

This is a special case of a general type of proof. If $P(x)$ and $Q(x)$ are statements, and we want to prove:

$$\forall x:P(x)\implies Q(x)\tag2$$ we need not know whether $P(x)$ is ever true or not, we just need to show **if** $P(x)$ is true, we can conclude $Q(x).$

There are theorems like “If $n$ is an odd perfect number, then <something else about $n$>.” The proofs might start, “Let $n$ be an odd perfect number….” We still don’t know if odd perfect numbers exist, but we can still prove things about them.

The other meaning would be where you only needed one element of $A.$ Then saying, “Let $x\in A\dots$” requires you to prove $A$ is non-empty first.

It does take some time to get used to these two usages, since nothing in the language, only the context, hints at the meaning.

It might be better in the first example to say, “If $x\in A,$ then… “ rather than “Let $x\in A…$”

Comment: I give some other better alternatives in [this post](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/a/18155/1550), such as "given any", and the keyword is "any" which unambiguously indicates the ∀ quantifier.